# concurrency in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, api, concurrency, server-side

I'm at a point in my PHP server-side API where I am making lots of MySQL queries and I'd like to speed it up by having mutliple threads working on different queries and then return the results.

But how do I make another thread in PHP? I am passing around POST params, so a simple `shell_exec()` could work, but seems kinda of unsafe. Options I'm considering:

1) Make a cURL request using the parameters I have, process the JSON from the request and then return

2) Call a `shell_exec()` with PHP CLI and somehow (how would I do this??) process the response in PHP

what are the best options here?

Comment: Usually it is done with queue and worker, that monitors it

Comment: you set up some queue managing software (ie rabbitmq). Then your script adds task to the queue and some background worker performs it

Comment: Instead of going this complex route, it may be worth investigating alternatives like optimizations and caching. If your bottleneck is indeed waiting for a query that cannot possibly be sped up or cached any further and you think that executing more queries in parallel will actually help, establishing several connections from the same script, firing off the queries using non-blocking APIs and getting the results afterwards may be a lot easier.

Comment: several connections? non-blocking APIs written in PHP? not sure what specifically you are saying - my point was that I wanted to asynchrnously make calls and return them, my question was _how_ to do this

Comment: http://gonzalo123.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/speed-up-php-scripts-with-asynchronous-database-queries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no threading support in PHP. You can however use the [`pcntl`](http://php.net/pcntl) extension to spawn and manage forks, but it would be best to have a second look at your algorithms if you reached the conclusion that things should be done with threading.

An option for processing long running operations asynchronously would be to store them in a database, and have a background worker process take them from the database, calculate the results, then store the results in the database. Then the front facing script would look them up in the database to see if they're completed and what the result is.

Comment: how are large scale websites built in PHP if that is the case?

Comment: it would seem to me that performance-critical APIs / sites with many database interactions would need concurrency

Comment: @lollercoaster: and storage concurrency has nothing to do with php concurrency. Storages deal with it themselves

Comment: @lollercoaster, most intensive tasks can be accomplished with a combination of background processing and caching.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [pcntl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). PHP doesn't support true threading at all, so you'll have to implement pseudo-threads by fork()ing. Note that fork()ing a process is much "heavier" than spawning a thread.

Answer (score 2):

PHP hasn't implemented threads (and likely never will) because many of PHP's libraries are NOT thread safe. That alterative is `pcntl` which wraps the C `fork` function.

I've [created a handy wrapper](https://gist.github.com/2495273) for these functions that let me manage them at a higher level.

```
$thread1 = new Thread( function( $thread ) {
    sleep( 4 );
    $thread->write( "Hello\n" );
} );

$thread2 = new Thread( function( $thread ) {
    sleep( 5 );
    $thread->write( "World\n" );
} );

$thread3 = new Thread( function( $thread ) {
    sleep( 6 );
} );

print $thread1->read(); // time: 0 -> 4
print $thread2->read(); // time: 4 -> 5
$thread3->join(); // time 5 -> 6

// More advanced handling:
// Thread::selectUntilJoin( array( $thread1, $thread2, $thread3 ), function () { ... }, function () { ... } );
```

Comment: "meaning the functions can't be called from different threads" --- it is not correct definition for TS code